# Dealing with array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes

```
def factory_girl_users
  Hash[user_1: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user), user_2: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:automated_user_1)]
end
# {:user_1=>{:username=>"username_1", :password=>"password"}, :user_2=>{:username=>"username_2", :password=>"password"}}
```

I then want to select a random user so put the hash of factory_girl_users into an array and select one using `pop`

```
def choose_user
  user_array = factory_girl_users.to_a
  @user = user_array.pop
end
```

So at this stage @user would look like

```
[:user_2, {:username=>"username_2", :password=>"password"}]
```

My first question is how do i access the username and password values

And secondly how would i just get `{:username=>"username_2", :password=>"password"}` returned

I want to be able to access the values by doing

```
@user[:username]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't care about the keys (from the hash), you can do this:

```
user_array = factory_girl_users.values
@user = user_array.pop
@user[:password]
```

Comment: what is the difference in doing `factory_girl_users.values.to_a` and `factory_girl_users.values`. What i mean is both create an array dont they?

Comment: @Richlewis: you're right, `.to_a` is redundant here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

(1) access the username and password values

```
hash = [:user_2, {:username=>"username_2", :password=>"password"}]
hash[1]
=> {:username=>"username_2", :password=>"password"}
hash[1][:username]
=> "username_2"
hash[1][:password]
=> "password"
```

(2)

```
 user_array.pop[1]
 => {:username=>"username_2", :password=>"password"}
```

Comment: Thaks, also just found out i could make it easier for myself by making an array of just the `hash` values,  `user_array = factory_girl_users.values` your answer helps though, thanks